# Kill TCP connections on a Mac in Terminal

Tags: macos

I just want to kill a specific tcp connection on my mac (similar to tcpkill on linux). By port or ip, preferably port but i'll settle. I don't want to pay for a service or download another software, I want the simple terminal command that will allow me to do this like tcpkill.

I've tried fixing up the rules on my firewall, and tried to make a bash script so it would run but to no success because the tutorial I found was very old.

Why does this seem to be such a difficult task to find information on, or do?

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1**

You can install tcpkill. It is part of the dsniff package which is in [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org). You said you don't want to install other software. Nevertheless MacPorts is really useful if you work from the command line. I suggest you check it out.

**Option 2**

On StackOverflow there is a related post: [Find (and kill) process locking port 3000 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855127/find-and-kill-process-locking-port-3000-on-mac). The suggested solution there is to create a function that kills all connection on a specific port:

```
function killport() { lsof -i TCP:$1 | awk '/LISTEN/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9 }
```

If you change the function by taking away the argument the function should kill all applications that have an open TCP connection.

```
function killport() { lsof -i TCP | awk '/LISTEN/ {print $2}' | xargs kill -9 }
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this.

Disclaimer 2: It's a brute force method and can have some serious side effects. I would recommend against this approach.

Comment: I found some OS X binaries for dsniff here (in case you aren't a MacPorts user) here: FWIW http://packages.macports.org/dsniff (apparently homebrew doesn't have a recipe for it anymore, as of today)

Comment: There is a homebrew recipe for it in the `homebrew/boneyard` tap.

Comment: There is a dsniff fork that contains a working `tcpkill` version: https://github.com/ggreer/dsniff

Comment: How can I install dsniff using MacPorts? I installed MacPorts, what is the next step?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, you have to install openssl@1.0 in order for dsniff to compile successfully.