# Is there a way to remove a server account network entry from terminal?

Tags: network, osx-server, preferences, accounts, defaults

I have a Mac mini running Mac OS X 10.10.3. It has an open directory server configured in the server account network configuration in 'Users and groups'.

Is there a way to remove that server account network entry from terminal?

To be more specific, I want to log in with the local user and remove the connection with the directory service for that particular server using the terminal.

Comment: Please be more specific. What have you tried? What type of server? Of course it could be possible but what server?

Comment: Simply, I have a mac mini running Mac OS X 10.10.3. It has an open directory server configured in the server account network configuration in Users and groups. Now, my question is: is there a way to remove that server account network entry from terminal?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.kombitz.com/2013/11/07/how-to-delete-a-local-user-using-command-line-on-mac-os-x/) helpful? It deletes a local user

Comment: Unfortunately not, what I want is to log in with the local user and remove the connection with the directory service for that particular server using the terminal

Comment: I guess you could kill the connection. [This](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/134714/kill-tcp-connections-on-a-mac-in-terminal) might help. The first answer

Comment: I'm sorry but unfortunately it's not helpful. Do you know if the server account network's value is stored in a plist file? Maybe it's possibile to edit it with the command "defaults".

Comment: Probably not. defaults is for user settings. But I might be wrong. A this point, I can't help...

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a few hours I've finally found the command!

```
dsconfigldap -r *servername*
```